# How to test for file absence with serverspec?

Tags: linux, configuration-management, testing, automated-testing

The [serverspec guide on resource types](http://serverspec.org/resource_types.html) doesn't explain how to test for the absence of a file, rather than its presence. This is the best I could come up with:

```
describe command('/bin/bash -c "[[ ! -e /var/foo ]]"') do
  its(:exit_status) { should eq 0 }
end
```

That seems terribly clunky, but better than [leveraging the builtins](http://serverspec.org/resource_types.html#file):

```
describe file('/var/foo') do
  it { should_not be_file }
  it { should_not be_directory }
  it { should_not be_socket }
  it { should_not be_symlink }
end
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The serverspec `File` object now responds `.exists?`, so this works:

```
describe file('/var/foo') do
  it { should_not exist }
end
```

The feature [was added](https://github.com/serverspec/serverspec/pull/519) in serverspec v2.17.0.